# How can I pipe text output from a Ruby irb / pry session to a linux filter?

Tags: ruby, filter, pipe, irb, pry

I scrape some webpages, and got html text. I would like to see the html as plain text. How can I pipe the text which is in a variable to a linux filter ( with statements "system" or %x{ } ) ?

Comment: Your title says you're using IRB. Is that how you create the HTML? If so, don't. IRB is for temporary testing, not running production code. Instead, put your code into a text file and tell Ruby to run it. Since you're not showing us your code we can't tell whether it'll run correctly for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing a here document. Like so:

```
irb << ! > output_file
IO.popen('dmidecode -t bios').each{ |i| puts i }
!
```

Comment: I am using the Mechanize or the Watir-Webdriver gems. Meanwhile I realized that they have methods to dump the page as pure plain text. For example with Phantomjs, if "b" is the browser object, I have to simply call "b.text".